# Warning "Map update loop missed its desired rate" keeps on comming

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i am setting up Navigation stack as explained in the [Navigation Stack Setup Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), My my configuration files are as follows:-

**1. base_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
    TrajectoryPlannerROS:
    # for details see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner
    max_vel_x: 0.2
    min_vel_x: 0.05
    max_rotational_vel: 0.5
    min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1

    acc_lim_th: 3.2
    acc_lim_x: 2.5
    acc_lim_y: 0

    holonomic_robot: true

    # goal tolerance parameters
    yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
    xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
    latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
```

**2. costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0
  footprint: [[0.305, 0.278], [0.04, 0.193], [-0.04, 0.193], [-0.282, 0.178], [-0.282, -0.178], [-0.04, -0.193], [0.04, -0.193], [0.305, -0.278]]
 #footprint: [[0.075, 0.178], [0.04, 0.193], [-0.04, 0.193], [-0.282, 0.178], [-0.282, -0.178], [-0.04, -0.193], [0.04, -0.193], [0.075, -0.178]]
 #robot_radius: ir_of_robot
 inflation_radius: 0.6

 observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

 laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: openni_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**3. global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
  global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
```

**4. local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
  local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  # origin_x: -0.115
  origin_x: 7.5
  origin_y: 7.5
  resolution: 0.05
```

**5. move_base_param.yaml**

```
controller_frequency: 10
controller_patience: 15.0
oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.5

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
max_vel_x: 0.45
min_vel_x: 0.1
max_rotational_vel: 1.0
min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

acc_lim_th: 1.0
acc_lim_x: 0.5
acc_lim_y: 0.5
path_distance_bias: 50.0
goal_distance_bias: 0.8
holonomic_robot: false
```

**6. move_base.launch**

```
<launch>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/map/map.pgm 0.05"/>

  <!--- You can see original move_base.launch -->
  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find usarsim_inf)/launch/usarsim.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />



  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" respawn="false" name="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=lms200" >
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" name="rviz">
  </node>
</launch>
```

**now where i launch the move_base.launch file everything goes fine but i am getting a warning as:-**

```
  [ WARN] [1413922749.722348193]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 2.0000Hz... the loop actually took 2.9248 seconds
```

**in my previous question i asked about the reason of this warning but still i am confused and could not remove this warning, please help me out so that i can solve it.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195523/warning-%22map-update-loop-missed-its-desired-rate%22-keeps-on-comming/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xqshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20542/xqshan/) on 2014-10-21**:
I have met the same problem,the warning always occured when i tried to change the value of controller_frequency in both larger and smaller conditions. But it seems only a little harm in  the running process.I also expect someone who can point out the real problem it is ,with much appreciation.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-22**:
What system are you running on and what sensors and global map size do you get? 3 seconds for an update seems really slow. Does this happen only once?

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-22**:
@dornhege i am using ros-fuerte on ubuntu machine.
& a p3at in USARSim (on windows machine).

MAP SIZE: 4000, 4000

Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-22**:
@dornhege Thanks for you reply.

i have change update frequency from 2.0 to 0.25, now no such kind of warning appears.

but getting a new warning

```
 Aborting because a valid plan could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-22**:
@dornhege

[click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ft15acvu42lfq5z/error_aborting%20because%20of%20valid%20plan.docx?dl=0) to view the terminal output

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-23**:
You just changed the parameters to suppress the warning without solving that it is slow. The other warning could be due to the robot/navigation setup now or still caused by the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that your map cannot be updated as fast as you've parameterized it. You can choose to use a smaller or lower resolution map or provide more computational power.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-22**:
@rfoote then what should be the new value, & where i need to improve. please explain.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-02**:
There's a [tuning guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's a potential bug in navigation stack. please see:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/468

comment r.sleep() will solve the issue.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2018-08-30**:
where should the r.sleep() be added?